# How to set usrp transmitting time and receiving time in GNU radio

Tags: time, gnuradio, receiver, usrp, software-defined-radio

I'm currently using two USRP X310, one for transmitting and another one for receiving. Programming is done using GNU Radio. I want to transmit a chirp signal to find the distance between both USRPs.

However, before I can do it, I need to find out the receiving time of the signal. Anyone know how to do it using GNU radio?

Answer (score 2):

The GNU Radio UHD source will produce `rx_time` stream tags on streaming start and after every stream disruption, which will give you the device time for the first sample. After that, it's that time + `n_samples_since_tag / sampling_rate` to get the current time.

See

- [details on stream tags](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorial_Programming_Topics#52-Stream-Tags)
- [documentation of the usrp_source](http://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1uhd_1_1usrp__source.html#a8ba918061af928ee7c01e7124580eb82)

for details, which are not easy to explain here, but nicely covered in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

rx_time tag may give you the time when the USRP receives noise, not the time of reception of desired signal. The only way i can think of is calculate the FFT of the signal and get the time when the PSD of the FFT goes above certain level